# Dart can't find git dependency but `flutter pub get` downloaded it

Tags: flutter, plugins

I've created a plugin that I'm testing against a secondary flutter app. this purpose is to understand / validate my plugin is available to the integrating app, it's clearly not.

I've included the dependency as follows:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
   sdk: flutter
 concierge:
    git: git@github.com:flybits/flutter-concierge-plugin.git
```

After running `flutter pub get` I see the .flutter-depenedency file contains the plugin and a file path to the plugin.

```
concierge=/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/.pub-cache/git/flutter-concierge-plugin-bf25c6bd87bd88f3c012ef06acd886bd6f2e68ec/
firebase_auth=/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-3.3.20/
```

And so on.

checked on disk and found the directory. I'm confident the command worked. My issue is when I go to use it the demo app cannot find this plugin.

```
import 'package:concierge/concierge.dart';
```

but its able to find `firebase_auth`

The only different I can tell are the directories are different, one with /git/ the other with /hosting/

*I've installed flutter using HomeBrew*

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're observing.  Is the `pubspec.yaml` snippet you've shown the one in the root directory of your demo app?  The indentation is inconsistent.  Is that how your file actually is?  You talk also about `firebase_auth`, but it's unclear what the relevance is since you don't seem to have a dependency on `firebase_auth`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. The pubspec.yaml is an example. The file itself works when I run `flutter pub get`. As for `firebase_auth` I was giving an example of a dependency that works when I try to use its code via VSCode by adding

```
import 'package:concierge/concierge.dart'; <-- fails 
import 'package:firebase_auth/flutter_auth.dart'; <-- works
```

The difference I can see is firebase_auth is found in `.pub_cache/hosting` while mine is found in `.pub_cache/git`

Comment: Does running `flutter analyze` also report the error?  If so, I would recommend distilling your problem down to a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the solutions below, verify:

- if the `pubspec.yaml` is correctly idented.
- if your `SSH` is working with GitHub

---

If is everything ok, look if your package is correctly configured:

- The main package's `file name` must be the `package name`.
- The main package's file must had a line like:

  `library your_package_name;` in your case `library concierge;`
- The package's name in `pubspec.yaml` must have the same name of the main file.

---

If still all ok, try get the package like this in your project pubspec:

```
concierge:
  git:
    url: git@github.com:flybits/flutter-concierge-plugin.git
    ref: main
```

**Remember** to verify the `git` branch used if use this.

Comment: Hey Thanks! this worked. I'm not sure what type of magic this is but solved my problem.